# nedb method update and delete creates a new entry instead updating existing one

Tags: javascript, node.js, nedb

I'm using [nedb](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb)  and I'm trying to update an existing record by matching it's `ID`, and changing a `title` property.
What happens is that a new record gets created, and the old one is still there.
I've tried several combinations, and tried googling for it, but the search results are scarce.

```js
var Datastore = require('nedb');
var db = {
    files: new Datastore({ filename: './db/files.db', autoload: true })
};

db.files.update(
  {_id: id}, 
  {$set: {title: title}}, 
  {}, 
  callback
);
```

What's even crazier when performing a delete, a new record gets added again, but this time the record has a weird property:
`{"$$deleted":true,"_id":"WFZaMYRx51UzxBs7"}`

This is the code that I'm using:

```js
db.files.remove({_id: id}, callback);
```

Comment: Is this a desired behavior?

Comment: This has nothing to do with nw.js or express. Please don't tag questions with unrelated tags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the nedb docs it says followings :

> localStorage has size constraints, so it's probably a good idea to set
> recurring compaction every 2-5 minutes to save on space if your client
> app needs a lot of updates and deletes. See [database compaction](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb#compacting-the-database) for
> more details on the append-only format used by NeDB.

> **Compacting the database**
>
> Under the hood, NeDB's persistence uses an append-only format, meaning
> that all updates and deletes actually result in lines added at the end
> of the datafile. The reason for this is that disk space is very cheap
> and appends are much faster than rewrites since they don't do a seek.
> The database is automatically compacted (i.e. put back in the
> one-line-per-document format) everytime your application restarts.
>
> You can manually call the compaction function with
> yourDatabase.persistence.compactDatafile which takes no argument. It
> queues a compaction of the datafile in the executor, to be executed
> sequentially after all pending operations.
>
> You can also set automatic compaction at regular intervals with
> yourDatabase.persistence.setAutocompactionInterval(interval), interval
> in milliseconds (a minimum of 5s is enforced), and stop automatic
> compaction with yourDatabase.persistence.stopAutocompaction().
>
> Keep in mind that compaction takes a bit of time (not too much: 130ms
> for 50k records on my slow machine) and no other operation can happen
> when it does, so most projects actually don't need to use it.

I didn't use this but it seems , it uses localStorage and it has append-only format for update and delete methods.

When investigated its source codes, [in that search](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%24%24deleted) in persistence.tests they wanted to sure checking `$$delete` key also they have mentioned `If a doc contains $$deleted: true, that means we need to remove it from the data``.

So, In my opinion you can try to compacting db manually, or in your question; second way can be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll check it out in a few hours, once I get home from work :)

Comment: ...and you can force a single compaction of the database with ’db.persistence.compactDatafile()’.